# What is a Good Web Service Tutorial for Leiningen2, Clojure and Ring?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure, ring

I am attempting to learn how to and then create a web service in clojure, and I am looking for tutorials that help illustrate the process.  I am new to clojure.  It seems like every tutorial is geared towards either previous version of leiningen, or compojure, etc, but none really give a good idea of what to do.  Any advice on this?  Starting from using leiningen 2.1.2, is there a tutorial to teach me how to create a web service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as using ring and compojure I see no diference between leiningen 2.0.x and 2.1.x, so it's likely fine to use tutorials that mention older versions of this tool.

There are some nice tutorials mentioned on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122749/good-current-documentation-and-or-tutorials-for-compojure-ring-development) Though my current personal recommendation goes to the chapter on web programmin in [Clojure Programming](http://www.clojurebook.com/)

Comment: Cheers, thanks.  Just picked up the book and reading the SO post now.